# Why is my Application's Icon grayed out in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, permissions, osx-snow-leopard, finder

In the `Applications` folder on OS X I have a few programs that are "grayed out":

[image: image.jpg]

I tried running `Repair Disk Permissions` in the `Disk Utility` but it doesn't fix this.

I tried looking at the permissions manually in Terminal:

```
$ ll /Applications | grep -E Goo\|Mate

drwxr-xr-x@   3 cwd  wheel        102B Sep 25 04:15 Google Chrome.app
drwxr-xr-x@   3 cwd  admin        102B Mar 14  2011 TextMate.app
```

This behavior is preventing the Apps from showing up in Spotlight Search and also Quicksilver.

I don't know much about extended attributes but I'm going to try and provide a little more info:

```
$ xattr TextMate.app/
com.apple.FinderInfo
```

And possibly this will also help:

```
$ xattr -l TextMate.app
com.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
```

- Why is this happening?
- How can I fix it?

**Update**

Per @danielbeck's request, the results of

```
ls -lae@ /Applications/{TextMate,iTunes,Growl,Google\ Chrome}.app/Contents/MacOS
```

output:

```
drwxrwxr-x@ 3 root  wheel    102 Sep 25 05:09 .
    com.apple.FinderInfo       32 
drwxrwxr-x@ 8 cwd   wheel    272 Sep 25 05:09 ..
    com.apple.FinderInfo       32 
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel  14048 Sep 25 05:09 Google Chrome

Growl.app/Contents/MacOS:
total 744
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel      102 Sep 19 18:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel      408 Oct 14 23:19 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  1204176 Oct 14 23:19 Growl

TextMate.app/Contents/MacOS:
total 22856
drwxr-xr-x  3 cwd   admin       102 Mar 15  2011 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 cwd   admin       238 Mar 13  2011 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 cwd   admin  11700088 Mar 15  2011 TextMate

iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS:
total 98240
drwxr-xr-x   9 root  wheel       306 Oct  2 09:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel       340 Oct  2 09:37 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  40631056 Sep 10 01:34 iTunes
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     34448 Sep 10 01:34 iTunesASUHelper
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel       102 Oct  2 09:37 iTunesHelper.app
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   6591200 Sep 10 01:34 libgnsdk_dsp.1.9.5.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    563040 Sep 10 01:34 libgnsdk_musicid.1.9.5.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   1882736 Sep 10 01:34 libgnsdk_sdkmanager.1.9.5.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    582536 Sep 10 01:34 libgnsdk_submit.1.9.5.dylib
```

As seen in the Finder:

[image: image.jpg]

Comment: Can you run the apps? Verify doesn't do anything, by the way. `Repair Disk Permissions` is what you need to run.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -lae@ {TextMate,iTunes,Growl,Google\ Chrome}.app/Contents/MacOS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems odd and I've not seen it, but side loaded apps should have permissions similar to the snapshot below. I would use finder to change the admin group to read only to ensure you can make changes to this folder and then revert the permissions to match mine below:

[image: Permissions for Chrome]

The posix and ACL permissions should be as follows for Chrome out of the box...

```
Air:~ mike$ls -lO /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  8 mike  admin  - 272 Oct 10 03:57 Contents
Air:~ mike$ls -lae@ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x   3 mike  admin   102 Oct 10 03:09 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 74 root  admin  2516 Oct 28 20:48 ..
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxrwxr-x   8 mike  admin   272 Oct 10 03:57 Contents
```

Unless you've gotten the launch services database in a muss or somehow enabled gatekeeper, it's likely a sign the app folders are not readable or executable by your OS user.

Comment: the permissions on those apps are the same as the other apps in the /Applications folder. also you should be able to see from the original question that the application folders are readable and executable by everyone, i.e. `drwxr-xr-x@`

Comment: What happens when you use the finder to touch/change/adjust the permissions on one of the dimmed apps? I'm more used to using the capital **O** option to check for file flags since you've already covered ACL with the **e** option. While you're in the info window, it would be interesting to see if the icon preview section is also dimmed like the normal finder window.

Comment: no luck with your suggested. added a screenshot in the question.

Comment: Grr - I'll leave this up unless you'd rather have it unanswered. I was hoping this would help or maybe help someone else with a similar issue. I'll bookmark it if I can think of a better way to narrow down the cause. It'll be a pain to delete each app and re-download them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with Chrome in El Capitan (so quite a time after you asked). After OSX restart it always showed grayed-out, then on first run its icon turned full-color.

Per this [advice](https://spoonjab.com/how-to-fix-grayed-outtransparent-icons-in-dock-mac-osx/) I used:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock showhidden -bool NO
```

and it stopped making the icon grayed-out on boot (likewise turning it `YES` again caused Chrome to appear grayed-out again, although on boot, not after `killall Dock`)